# MySQL Case not working in MySQL update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm relatively new to web development and currently working on a chat feature. I have a message table where I store conversations between two users. Now, I want to implement a functionality where if one user deletes a message, it remains visible to the other user until they also delete it. To manage this, I've added two columns in my database table to handle the delete criteria. However, when I run my SQL query to update these columns, it returns true but the corresponding database column remains unchanged. The default value for these columns is 0 (zero). Below is the SQL query I'm using:

```
UPDATE messages 
SET  delete_two = CASE WHEN delete_one > 0 THEN 9600  ELSE delete_two END,
     delete_one = COALESCE(delete_one,9600)
WHERE id = 367
```

Anyone help please to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: what's not updated? delete_one or delete_two?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev both columns not update due to default value of zero

Comment: @jarlh I am using mySQL

Comment: Add some before sample data and the wanted after data - all as formatted text.

Comment: @jarlh if I use following query

"UPDATE messages 
SET  delete_two = CASE WHEN delete_one = 0 THEN 9600  ELSE delete_two END,
     delete_one = COALESCE(delete_one,9600)
WHERE id = 367"
Then this update only delete_two column for first user and for second user this update this column value for second user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COALESCE` works on `null` and `not null` values. If you want to compare with `0` then you need to use `IF`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE messages 
SET  delete_two = CASE WHEN delete_one > 0 THEN 9600  ELSE delete_two END,
     delete_one = IF(delete_one = 0 , 9600, delete_one)
WHERE id = 367
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4607d8/1/0)**.

Answer (score 0):

Default (0) has nothing to do with the update statement. I can't understand the logic in that query...

First of all, I am not sure true usage of these columns. What are the possible values there? Is that just the indicator if the row is updated or not? Then I can't understand why do you use 9600 as the default value in COALESCE. Why not 1?

Another thing I can't understand how can that happen that you update the message for 2 users in 1 update statement? How can that logically happen?

Now let's comeback to your query, if you still need to update then:

```
UPDATE messages 
SET  delete_two = CASE WHEN delete_one > 0 THEN 9600  ELSE delete_two END,
     delete_one = CASE WHEN delete_one = 0 OR delete_one IS NULL THEN 9600 ELSE  delete_one END
WHERE id = 367
```

I've added checking for delete_one IS NULL because you are still able insert NULL to that column (of course if it is nullable) even if there is DEFAULT constraint.